# How do you interpret "12 hrs power" in Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management, activity-monitor, energy

When hovering over the *12 hrs power* column header in the Energy tab of Activity Monitor, it says:

> Average Energy Impact over the last 12 hours or since the Mac started. Lower is better.

In my case, WhatsApp is "37.34". Since we're told "lower is better", it can be inferred that it is using a *lot* of energy relative to other applications - but 37.34 *what* exactly? (is it a % of total power use, an absolute measure in some electrical metric, or something else?)

[image]

Comment: Detailed here: https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2015/08/26/what-does-the-os-x-activity-monitors-energy-impact-actually-measure/

Answer (score 2):

I found the article [What does the OS X Activity Monitor’s “Energy Impact” actually measure?](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2015/08/26/what-does-the-os-x-activity-monitors-energy-impact-actually-measure/) that does great work in figuring out what this Energy Impact is.

In summary, this is the formula (taken directly from the article)

```
|elapsed_us| is the length of the sample period
|used_us| is the time this process was running during the sample period

  %CPU = (used_us * 100.0) / elapsed_us

  POWER = if is_a_kernel_process()
            0
          else
            ((used_us + IDLEW * 500) * 100.0) / elapsed_us
```

> The IDLEW column is the number of package idle exit wakeups.

Every MacBook model seems to have a different "tax" on idle wakeups (some 200, some other 500) but follows the same formula.

This means that this is not a real unit since it's a form of percentage but adding two different units (CPU% + microsecond tax on `idlew`). CPU% could be 0, but (IDLEW * 500) could be 1500, etc.

I'm unsure how to interpret this value "on a day-to-day basis" other than "lower is better." Most apps on my Mac (Sublime Text, Docker, iTerm...) are < 10, and only Chrome is at ~250, which seems natural given the resources each consumes.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is a percentage (%) figure. So 37.34% of the total power consumed in that 12 hour period. 12 hours taken as the preceding 12 hours from the current time.

As if you think it is hours then how do you get 37.34 hours in the last 12 hours?

Comment: +1 Hours doesn't make sense. Percent, maybe, but there's an unaccounted ~38%. My hunch was some energy metric (volts/watts/amps etc). But I can't find documentation on it, and I don't know how to explore Activity Monitor for more detailed energy info.

Comment: @stevec the other "lost" energy could be for the other bits like speakers as energy is consumed by many things not only apps.

Comment: I currently see a value of 114.88 for Chrome on my machine. In the past 12 hours I was on battery power down to about 80%, followed by charging to 100%, followed by battery power down to 10%.

Comment: Not sure it can be %. My Mac says VS Code consumed 634,31.

Comment: VSCode does consume a lot of ressources (running on Electron, haven't tested web on chrome/other). And from my tests even "classic" plugins like TypeScript and ESLint can ramp up cpu & ram usage to large amounts

Comment: As others have said, it's possible for this value to be well over 100, so it can't be a percentage (I currently show Terminal with a value of almost 4700)

Comment: @Elezar then provide a knowledgeable answer and improve on mine.