# What's the unit of "12 hr power" in the energy section of activity monitor?

Tags: power, power-management, activity-monitor

In the "energy" section of activity monitor, there is a heading "12 hr power".

Is there a the unit of this quantity so that I can convert it to watts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you interpret "12 hrs power" in Activity Monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441956/how-do-you-interpret-12-hrs-power-in-activity-monitor)

Comment: @SolarMike Apparently, no. In particular, the figure can be larger than 100, so it cannot be a percentage.

Answer (score 2):

It's "energy impact", the same measure in as in the first column, except averaged over a 12 hour period.  It's unitless and doesn't imply any quantitative wattage.

In the Help file, Apple defines energy impact as

> A relative measure of the current energy consumption of the app
> (lower is better)

In 2015, an engineer from Mozilla performed an analysis on [what constitutes energy impact](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2015/08/26/what-does-the-os-x-activity-monitors-energy-impact-actually-measure/), and found that it was (back then):

> the formula used to compute “Energy Impact” is machine model-specific, and includes the following factors: CPU usage, wakeup frequency, quality of service class usage, and disk, GPU, and network activity.

Presumably the measure has evolved since then, but probably has similar underlying factors. It would make for an interesting experiment to measure the actual wattage consumed by the Mac and then graph it to see what the relationship is, but I have not seen anyone publish that work online.